# Symfony - custom firewall setup for API platform

Tags: php, symfony, firewall, api-platform.com

I am trying to restrict access to my Symfony 5.4 application API (running on API platform) by a host (e.g. allow only local network clients). I have this setup, but when accessing the "/api" I am always getting the API plartform (Swagger UI) home page regardles the host IP I am trying it from:

`firewalls:
dev:
    pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    security: false

api: 
    pattern: ^/api/
    stateless: true
    provider: app_user_provider
    jwt: ~
    security: true
    host: 127.0.0.1

main:
    form_login:
        login_path: app_login
        check_path: app_login

    lazy: true
    provider: app_user_provider

    logout:
        path: app_logout
        invalidate_session: true
        target: app_login`


What I am missing here? It looks like the API platform is "above" the Symfony framework. Does it mean it is not possible to configure security? Or do I have to do it on the HTTP server level?

I want to get the HTTP 403 error when doing the "/api" out of the restricted network area.

Answer (score 0):

set this config for disable docs and entry point

```
// config/packages/api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
    enable_entrypoint: false
    enable_docs: false
```

read more here:
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/configuration/
and here
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-security/production-docs

Comment: Thank you, it helped me to get better survey over the further options. But what I actually need to achieve is to keep the API available (also in PROD), including the docs, but restrict the access to the local network.

It seems that this is doing what I need:
 access_control:
        - { path: ^/api, ips:  [192.168.0.30, 127.0.0.1] }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }

But I would still feel doubts about the mechanism handling the API platform routes in the Symfony framework.